# What is the difference between InDesign Paragraph composer and Single line composer?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

In the new InDesign CC under the Paragraph options there are 4 types of paragraph:

- adobe world ready single line composer
- adobe world ready paragraph composer
- adobe single line composer
- adobe paragraph composer

I know that the world ready is a function introduced for RTL languages, but what are the main differences between those types of paragraphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Paragraph composer" means that ID will shuffle hyphens and line breaks throughout an entire paragraph to make it "look better" according to some arcane Adobe algorithm.

"Single-line composer" means ID will only hyphenate where its internal dictionaries and your hyphenation settings tell it to hyphenate on a per-line basis, and other than checking "number of hyphens in a row," it won't rearrange your paragraph.

(Personally I get furious when Adobe tries to think it can do a better typesetting job than I can; if I put in a hyphen or a soft return, then by Thor I *want* it there, and I don't want the software telling me it doesn't like it.)

Comment: Yes annoying but Adobe knows, for a fact: That eventually, no matter how good a human may be, their algorithm will be better one day. Now adobe really should try to make their tool such that it works out the problems with you not against you. Anyway forcing hyphen is bad if you later use the same text elsewhere, so certainly adobe is on to something here.